# SQL Developer 19.1 doesn't show the matching list of table names in worksheet editor

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL Developer 19.1 - worksheet editor doesn't show matching list of table names from the schema. Eg. If I were to write a SQL query such as:

```
select * from TMP_EMPLOYEE_MASTER;
```

I am expecting SQL Developer to show me the table name after I have typed first few letters of the table name (eg. TMP_EM). But looks like SQL developer doesn't seem to be helping at all in highlighting the matching table names.

I know that this feature exists in SQL Developer. Just wondering why it isn't working

### Edit 1:

---

I tried below options but still not working:

CTL+spacebar.

Change the entries in the preferences as mentioned in the screenshot. But this didn't help. The auto complete/suggestion for table name is not coming at all.[image: Settings]

Comment: View > Log. Click on the Statements panel. You can then see the query(ies) we run to go get the list of tables for you. Look at that query. Run it yourself. What, if anything, comes back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have more than 10 tables that start with TMP

Increase the filter for Auto-Complete to something higher than 10 - or type more letters, or use Ctrl+Spacebar to 'force' the completion feature to fire.

[image]

Comment: it worked after doing the above changes. Also, I need to type in atleast 5-6 characters and 2nd attempt of CTRL+SPACE works everytime now.

Comment: great, happy to hear you got it going now

Answer (score 0):

That option is located in Tools - Preferences; search for "complet" and you'll see **Code Editor: Completion Insight**. Check both "SQL Worksheet" and "PL/SQL Editor" checkboxes, adjust popup speed if necessary.

Works for me ...